# Making a Let's Encrypt-secured site viewable on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: https, mobile, security-certificate, windows

I operate a web application that I intend to make available through HTTPS to users of barcode-scanning PDAs running Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional, which was Microsoft's branding for Windows Mobile 6.5 on non-cellular devices. But users of that operating system get an error that the Let's Encrypt certificate authority is not trusted. **How should I inform my Windows Mobile 6.x users about how to install the Let's Encrypt root certificate?**

[The site](https://5dsoftware.com/) had previously used GoDaddy as a CA. When I renewed the site's SSL certificate through Let's Encrypt, my clients reported receiving the following error message:

> Information you exchange with this site cannot be viewed or changed by others. However, there's a problem with the site's security certificate.
>
> - [Exclamation point in yellow triangle] The certificate was issued by a company you have not chosen to trust.
> - [Checkmark in green circle] The certificate date is valid.
> - [Checkmark in green circle] The certificate has a valid name matching the name of the page you are trying to view.

I obtained a device for testing and saw the same error on the [Let's Encrypt site](https://letsencrypt.org/) itself. I tried these:

- I downloaded the ["Let's Encrypt Authority X3" certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) in .txt format, renamed it to .cer, and opened it on the device. It showed a message that the certificate was installed.
- Following the "Cross Signing" instructions on the same page, I downloaded the ["DST Root" certificate](https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html), pasted it into a .txt file, added `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` on its own line at the top and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` on its own line at the bottom, renamed it to .cer, and opened it on the device. I got two prompts about the dangers of installing a certificate, and I clicked the not-Block button twice (I think the messages were "More" and "Install") and got a message that the certificate was installed.

But these still wouldn't let me view my site or letsencrypt.org. I know WM6.5 is SNI-ignorant, but that's not the problem because "The certificate has a valid name". What can my clients do to get LE's root certificate installed?

Comment: It just may be the client's browser being fussy. On some browsers (like opera), if the certificate is possibly invalid, a warning will appear asking if the user wants to continue to the site. Try launching your HTTPS site from various different browsers and see what happens.

Comment: @Mike IE does just that when the corresponding root cert isn't installed. The device I got didn't come with any browsers other than IE. What other browsers for WM6 should I recommend to users?

Comment: I use android for my portable devices and use opera on it. Opera might work with a windows phone but check the official store for windows mobile apps and see what free browsers are there that you can try.